# is there a way to increase outlook 2013 attachment pane?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

hi is there a way of making the attachment list area in the reading pane of Outlook 2013 bigger? i would like to see the list of all attachments with the email , without having to scroll down

[image: Outlook screenshot]